# Probability of a Brownian Motion to fall in a bandwidth

Tags: probability, random-walk

Let $X_t$ be defined as

$$
X_t = X_0+\int_0^t\sigma_{0}\,dW_s,
$$

where $W_s$ is a Wiener process and $\sigma_0\in\mathbb{R}^{+}/{0}$. Which is the probability

$$
\mathbb{P}\left[a<X_t-X_0<b\right] ? 
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^1 \sigma_0 dW_s = \sigma_0 W_t$ is a centered normal variable with variance $\sigma_0^2t$